# highcharts error 14 when passing time

Tags: jquery, laravel, highcharts

I'm in need of help passing info to Highcharts in order to chart durations. Part of the application I'm working on tracks the times of a baby's diaper changes. When run, I get highcharts error #14, which I know is the passing of a string, rather than a number. I tried changing the datatype of my x-axis, but the error still appears. I'd appreciate any help.

The graph code:

```
`$(function () { 
    $('#diaperContainer').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Diaper Chart'
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            title: {
                text: 'Time of Diaper Change'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Type of Change'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderRadius: 10,
            borderWidth: 3,
            shared: true,
        },
        series: [{
            data: [{{ $diaperData }}]
        }]
    });
});`
```

The logic in the event controller, pulling database info:

```
$diaperData = array();
    $diapers = $baby->diapers;

    foreach ($diapers as $diaper) {
        if ($diaper->number_one && $diaper->number_two){
            array_push($diaperData, "['" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($diaper->created_at)) . "', '3']");
        } elseif ($diaper->number_one){
            array_push($diaperData, "['" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($diaper->created_at)) . "', '1']");
        } elseif ($diaper->number_two) {
            array_push($diaperData, "['" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($diaper->created_at)) . "', '2']");
        }
    }
    $diaperData = join($diaperData, ',');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try dropping the ticks around the numbers 1, 2 and 3 in the event controller?

Comment: *facepalm*  I was passing single digit strings instead of integers. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

error 14 indicates the values are passed as strings instead of numbers.

Highcharts accepts numbers as data not strings

reference : http://www.highcharts.com/errors/14

Hope this will help you